# How to enable "Windows Hello" on Win10 desktop?

Tags: windows-10

Windows Hello lets you sign in with your face. I've got a webcam. Can I use this feature on my desktop? How? I don't see it under Settings / Accounts / Sign-in options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows Hello requires a specific set of hardware, namely an IR sensor camera to ensure it can distinguish between you and a photo of you.

See https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2015/03/17/making-windows-10-more-personal-and-more-secure-with-windows-hello/

Answer (score 2):

Further to Yossi's answer; I've used two devices that work with Hello:

1. A fingerprint Reader. Eikon make a couple of device forms that work with Hello. Amazon sell these ("Eikon Digital Privacy Manager USB Fingerprint Reader").
2. An Intel Real Sense Dev kit. You generally get this type of cam built into a laptop or tablet (Surface Pro 4?) but you can buy a dev kit as a stand alone device. See http://click.intel.com/intel-realsense-developer-kit.html

I've found the fingerprint readers to work reliably but not the RealSense Camera (the Intel service crashes and needs to be restarted all the time).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

For domain PC this requires this registry key setting to enable PIN login on domain joined machines:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System]
"AllowDomainPINLogon"=dword:00000001
```